# Installer want won't overwrite existing app !! i don't want to remove or uninstall Previous installation

Tags: c#, windows, installation

Install a windows application !! If Application Already existing in System then Update the Application and If Not Available in System Then Install it.

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution with 3 projects. It also has a Setup project which I build to create the installation.

It works fine when it's the first installation on a client PC. However, I then modify my project, and build a new Setup, and pass it onto clients. When this happens, the client has to first, manually, uninstall the last installation, and then run the setup.

If they run the setup, without uninstallaing, it seems it doesn't overwrite existing files (exe as well as the dlls). Usually it's just the exe that gets modified. However, it doesn't overwrite it. The version on the client machine seems to stay the same.

Is there a way to force it to overwrite?

Note that when I modify my main application project, I go to the properties of the project, assembly information, and increase the Assembly Version as well as the File Version.

Answer (score 1):

then change new installer version from it's property
[image]

for example first installer is version 1.0 and new installer is 2.0, so this is work as update instead of replace/remove